# Building JSON with array elements array values are undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, javascript-objects

What i am trying to achive is values are sent to via REST message, i am trying to place these values in a JSON format, so they can be placed into a field on a form.

```
var membersToAddArry = [];
membersToAddArry = request.queryParams.MembersToAdd.toString().split(";");    

   for(var x = 0; x < membersToAddArry.length-1; x++)
    {
        dn = membersToAddArry[x].toString();
        userJSONAdd["DistinguishedName"] = dn;
        userJSONAddn[x] = userJSONAdd;
    }
    return userJSONAddn;
```

Data sent:

```
CN=smcgh,OU=Lost-Found,OU=Corp,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com;
```

`CN=syouz,OU=Lost-Found,OU=Corp,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com;`

This returns:

```
    {
  "result": {
    "0": {
      "DistinguishedName": "CN=syouz,OU=Lost-Found,OU=Corp,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com"
    },
    "1": {
      "DistinguishedName": "CN=syouz,OU=Lost-Found,OU=Corp,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com"
    }
  }
}
```

The two bits of information are repeating how can i stop this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to split at semicolons and not at commas?

Comment: The last entry in the array is `""`, and you're *overwriting* `userJSONAdd` in each loop, so only the last element remains, which happens to be an empty string…

Comment: @KamenMinkov I need the full Distinguished name sadly

Comment: @deceze i changed my length to length -1 still did not fix the issue

Comment: Check your array `membersToAddArry ` to remove duplicates elements

Comment: @Fefux there only is the two values in the array :(

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what is duplicate. Is `CN=syouz,OU=Lost-Found,OU=Corp,DC=test,DC=COMPANY,DC=com` or the object `{"DistinguishedName": ..., "sAMAccountName": ...}`?

Comment: @Fefux if you look at the results the "0" is the same as the "1" object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinit your object `userJSONAdd` in the for-loop. Otherwise you add two times the same object but you change the value of the field `DistinguishedName` so you gets two times the same value :

```
var membersToAddArry = [];
membersToAddArry = request.queryParams.MembersToAdd.split(";");    

for(var x = 0; x < membersToAddArry.length-1; x++)
{
    userJSONAdd = {};
    dn = membersToAddArry[x].toString();
    userJSONAdd["DistinguishedName"] = dn;
    userJSONAddn[x] = userJSONAdd;
}
return userJSONAddn;
```